# Background image inside foreignObject hides other svg elements on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am having trouble adding a banner to a visualization I am creating using d3. I want to add the banner and then add text on top of the banner. This works on Chrome (the text renders "on top" of the image) but on Firefox it looks like the image is being rendered on top of the text. Anybody know why this works in Chrome but not Firefox and is there a way that I can achieve the same result in Firefox?

```
    var margin = {
    top: 155,
    right: 3,
    bottom: 3,
    left: 3
  },
  width = $(window).width() - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = $(window).height() - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
  transitioning;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, width])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, height])
  .range([0, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

var grandparent = svg.append("g").attr("class", "grandparent");

grandparent.append("rect")
  .attr("y", -margin.top)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", margin.top);

grandparent.append("foreignObject")
.attr("y", -margin.top)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", margin.top)
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .attr("class", "bannerDiv");

grandparent.append("text")
  .attr("x", 6)
  .attr("y", (-1 / 8) * margin.top)
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .style("fill", "#A5D867")
  .text("The text here");

function text(text) {
  text.attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.x) + 6;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.y) + 6;
    });
}
```

Please see this jsfiddle for an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rmw6snj6/

Comment: Use a rect with a pattern fill to display the image.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just out of curiosity, any (known) reason for this difference in behaviour between Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Yep sounds like a bug, is it known? This means `foreignObject` content is always at top? ah maybe https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984312

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Firefox : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984312

In the bug report, one given workaround is to set your `foreignObject`'s transform to `translate(0,0)`

```css
input:checked + svg foreignObject {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.bannerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2011/10/header-banner-design_64599.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

body {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<label>workaround</label><input type="checkbox" checked/>
<svg width="535" height="484">
  <g transform="translate(3,155)" style="shape-rendering: crispedges;">
    <g class="grandparent">
      <rect y="-155" width="529" height="155"></rect>
      <foreignObject y="-155" width="529" height="155">
        <div class="bannerDiv"></div>
      </foreignObject>
      <text x="6" y="-19.375" dy=".75em" style="fill: rgb(165, 216, 103);">The text here</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```